# Karatsuba Algorithm: splitting strings

Tags: c, algorithm, biginteger, karatsuba

I am trying to implement the Karatsuba algorithm in C.
I work with char strings (which are digits in a certain base), and although I think I have understood most of the Karatsuba algorithm, I do not get where I should split the strings to multiply.

For example, where should I cut *123 * 123*, and where should I cut *123 * 12*?
I can't get to a solution that works with both these calculations.

I tried to cut it in half and flooring the result when the number if odd, but it did not work, and ceiling does not work too.

Any clue?

Let a, b, c, and d be the parts of the strings.

- ### Let's try with 123 * 12

  **First try** (a = 1, b = 23, c = 1, d = 2) (fail)

  ```
  z0 = a * c = 1
  z1 = b * d = 46
  z2 = (a + b) * (c + d) - z0 - z1 = 24 * 3 - 1 - 46 = 72 - 1 - 46 = 25

  z0_padded = 100
  z2_padded = 250

  z0_padded + z1 + z2_padded = 100 + 46 + 250 = 396 != 123 * 12
  ```

  **Second try** (a = 12, b = 3, c = 12, d = 0) (fail)

  ```
  z0 = 144
  z1 = 0
  z2 = 15 * 12 - z1 - z0 = 180 - 144 = 36

  z0_padded = 14400
  z2_padded = 360

  z0_padded + z1 + z2_padded = 14760 != 1476
  ```

  **Third try** (a = 12, b = 3, c = 0, d = 12) (success)

  ```
  z0 = 0
  z1 = 36
  z2 = 15 * 12 - z0 - z1 = 144

  z0_padded = 0
  z2_padded = 1440

  z0_padded + z1 + z2_padded = 1476 == 1476
  ```
- ### Let's try with 123 * 123

  **First try** (a = 1, b = 23, c = 1, d = 23) (fail)

  ```
  z0 = 1
  z1 = 23 * 23 = 529
  z2 = 24 * 24 - z0 - z1 = 46

  z0_padded = 100
  z2_padded = 460

  z0_padded + z1 + z2_padded = 561 != 15129
  ```

  **Second try** (a = 12, b = 3, c = 12, d = 3) (success)

  ```
  z0 = 12 * 12 = 144
  z1 = 3 * 3 = 9
  z2 = 15 * 15 - z0 - z1 = 72

  z0_padded = 14400
  z2_padded = 720

  z0_padded + z1 + z2_padded = 15129 == 15129
  ```

  **Third try** (a = 12, b = 3, c = 1, d = 23) (fail)

  ```
  z0 = 12
  z1 = 3 * 23 = 69
  z2 = 15 * 24 - z0 - z1 = 279

  z0_padded = 1200
  z2_padded = 2799

  z0_padded + z1 = z2_padded = 4068 != 15129
  ```

Here, I do not get where I messed this up. Note that my padding method adds *n* zeroes at the end of a number where *n = m * 2* and *m* equals the size of the longest string divided by two.

## EDIT

Now that I have understood that `b` and `d` must be of the same length, it works almost everytime, but there are still exceptions: for example *1234*12*

```
a = 123
b = 4
c = 1
d = 2

z0 = 123
z1 = 8
z2 = 127 * 3 - 123 - 8 = 250

z0_padded = 1230000
z2_padded = 25000

z0_padded + z1 + z2_padded = 1255008 != 14808
```

Here, assuming I split the strings correctly, the problem is the padding, but I do not get how I should pad. I read on [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Karatsuba_algorithm&oldid=630576890#Pseudo_Code_Implementation) that I should pad depending on the size of the biggest string (see a few lines up), there should be another solution.

Comment: "Does not work" is not a very helpful description. It would be better if you described clearly what you're doing, what you expect to happen, and what actually happens instead. See the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more tips on asking good questions.

Comment: `First try (a = 1, b = 23, c = 1, d = 23)`, `z0_padded = 100` is a mistake. `z0_padded` should be 10000.  As long as `b` and `d` are equal lengths and you pad correctly, it should work.

Comment: Please write down in which situation you are padding on the left (and by how much), and the situation(s) where you pad on the right - _why_ do you pad on the right, _what does it mean_? (Oh, and please don't make your readers (including your later self) guess what padding you are referring to.)

Comment: This question has the names *z₀, z₁, and z₂* permuted with respect to the pseudocode on en.wikipedia. (The latter is consistent with the power of the base associated with each *zₓ* term.)

Answer (score 2):

The Karatsuba algorithm is a nice way to perform multiplications.
If you want it to work, `b` and `d` must be of the same length.

Here are two possibilities to compute 123x12 :

```
a= 1;b=23;c=0;d=12;
a=12;b= 3;c=1;d= 2;
```

Let's explain how it works for the second case :

```
123=12×10+3
 12= 1×10+2
123×12=(12×10+3)×(1×10+2)
123×12=12×1×100+             (12×2+3×1)×10+3×2
123×12=12×1×100+((12+3)×(1+2)-12×1-3×2)×10+3×2
```

Let's explain how it works for the first case :

```
123=1×100+23
 12=0×100+12
123×12=(1×100+23)×(0×100+12)
123×12=1×0×10000+              (1×12+23×0)×100+23×12
123×12=1×0×10000+((1+23)×(0+12)-1×0-23×12)×100+23×12
```

It also works with `10^k`,  `2^k` or `n` instead of `10` or `100`.

Comment: I did not know that b and d must have the same length. Is works well now, but there's still a problem, let's say you want to compute "1234*12" (a = 123, b = 4, c = 1, d = 2), z0 = ac = 123, and when I pad it (with 4 zeros in base ten) i will get a result much more larger than the real result

Comment: (The fourth lines of both explanation blocks show the terms of "schoolbook multiplication" (count 4 `×`(+2 "scaling ×")), the fifth lines those of Karatsuba's algorithm - while there are 5 `×`(+2 "scaling ×"), note two pairs of identical products occurring in terms of different weight.)